# How do I find the index of the maximum value in the list using Applescript?

Tags: list, indexing, applescript

I have an int list such as {18, 18, 18, 18, 22, 21}, I want to use Applescript to get the maximum value of this list, and get the maximum index, please teach me

Answer (score 2):

There are two stages to this:

1. Identifying the maximum value in the list;
2. Once the maximum value is known, determining the index of the last occurrence of this value in the list.

I'll use a sample list I generated myself in the examples I demonstrate below.  However, you can simply substitute your list for mine, and the processes described will work just as well, and produce the results specific to your input.

#### 1. Retrieving the maximum value in a numerical list

A quick-and-dirty way to get the maxium value in the list is to use a bash numeric `sort` command, and pick the last item:

```
    set L to {4, 24, 78, 32, 1.5, 32, 78, 4, 19, 78}

    set text item delimiters to linefeed
    do shell script "sort -n <<<" & quoted form of (L as text) & "| tail -n 1"
    --> 78
```

But, in the spirit of problem solving, the computer scientist's approach would be to iterate through the items in the list and perform these operations:

- Store the first item's value.
- If the next item is of greater value, then replace the currently stored value with the item we just assessed as being greater in value.
- If the next item is not of greater value, retain the currently stored value.

Once you reach the end of the list, the stored value must be equal to the greatest value item in the list.  At this point, we don't know its position in the list, but we know its value.

Here's the AppleScript that performs this process:

```
    set L to {4, 24, 78, 32, 1.5, 32, 78, 4, 19, 78}
    set max to L's first item

    repeat with x in L
        if x > max then set max to x's contents
    end repeat

    return max
    --> 78
```

#### 2. Determining the index of a given item in a list

Putting aside the maximum value for now, the second half of the problem involves being able to determine the position of any given item in an ordered list.

The most obvious solution to this is, as before, iterating through each item in the list and performing this operation:

- If the current item is equal to the target item, then append its index to the end of a list reserved for storing matching indices.

Once you reach the end of the list, your *matched indices* list will contain all the positions of the items whose value equal your target item's value; or the *matched indices* list will be an empty list, indicating that the main list does not contain the value we sought out.

The index of the first item in an AppleScript list is `1`.  Use the `length` property of a list to obtain the number of items in the whole list.

Here's a basic AppleScript:

```
    set L to {4, 24, 78, 32, 1.5, 32, 78, 4, 19, 78}
    set matches to {}
    set target to 78

    repeat with i from 1 to L's length
        if item i of L = the target then set end of matches to i
    end repeat

    return the matches
    --> {3, 7, 10}
```

#### 3. The combined process

Combining these two halves of the problem is as simple as running each half in sequence, being mindful to use the result from the first half of the process—the maximum value—as the target value to be sought out in the list:

```
    set L to {4, 24, 78, 32, 1.5, 32, 78, 4, 19, 78}
    set max to L's first item
    # Get maximum value
    repeat with x in L
        if x > max then set max to x's contents
    end repeat

    set matches to {}
    set target to max
    # Get index of maximum value
    repeat with i from 1 to L's length
        if item i of L = the target then set end of matches to i
    end repeat

    return the matches
    --> {3, 7, 10}
```

Finally, as you only want the maximum index, this is simply the last value in the `matches` list, i.e. `10`, which you obtain by replacing `return the matches` with this line:

```
    return the last item in matches
    --> 10
```

#### 4. Efficiency improvements

Having outlined the basic methods in each process, these aren't necessarily the fastest methods.  With lists containing only 10 items, inefficiency is not a noticeable concern.  If you had a list of 10,000 items, you would want to be able to reduce the time to get your result.

I think I'm correct in stating that there's no discernible way to speed up the first process in terms of algorithmic improvements: retrieving the maximum value necessitates comparing *every* item's magnitude and retaining the largest.

Determining the index, however, can be sped up given that we only need to determine the *last* occurrence of an item in the list.

Therefore, we can run the process as before, but making two changes:

1. Start from the end of the list instead the beginning.
2. Stop the process once we find the first match.

Here's the script:

```
    set L to {4, 24, 78, 32, 1.5, 32, 78, 4, 19, 78}
    set max to L's first item
    # Get maximum value
    repeat with x in L
        if x > max then set max to x's contents
    end repeat

    set target to max
    # Get index of maximum value
    repeat with i from L's length to 1 by -1
        if item i of L = the target then exit repeat
    end repeat

    return i
    --> 10
```

Note here the second `repeat` loop now runs backwards from the highest index down to `1`; and, we no longer require the `matches` list, so instead we simply exit the loop when a match is found, and see what value of `i` we were at.

One further improvement to the algorithm here would be to test for the null case to determine whether or not we really need to run through the list at all: the null case is the case where the list doesn't contain the value we seek.  AppleScript provides a builtin way to check this:

```
    if the target is not in L then return 0
```

and this line would sit immediately after `set target to max` and immediately before `repeat with i...`.

---

#### 5. Advanced improvements

Another way to improve efficiency, after addressing efficiency of the algorithms themselves, is to address the efficiency of the way the script is written.  This is more advanced than you need to concern yourself with now, but here's how I'd probably implement the algorithms if I were writing the script for my own use:

I would define a handler called `maximum()` that takes a list as its argument and returns the greatest value, and I would implement the scripting of this handler like so:

```
    on maximum(L as list)
        local L

        if L is {} then return {}
        if L's length = 1 then return L's first item

        script Array
            property x0 : L's first item
            property xN : rest of L
            property fn : maximum(xN)
            property predicate : x0 > fn
        end script

        tell the Array
            if its predicate is true then return its x0
            its fn
        end tell
    end maximum
```

This uses something called a **script object** to process the items of the list, which is much, much quicker in AppleScript than conventional iterative `repeat` loop.

Next, I would define a second handler called `lastIndexOf()` that takes a supplied value and a list as its two arguments, and returns the highest index at which the supplied value occurs in the given list.  My handler would look like this:

```
    on lastIndexOf(x, L as list)
        local x, L

        if x is not in L then return 0
        if L = {} then return

        script Array
            property x0 : L's last item
            property xN : reverse of rest of reverse of L
            property predicate : x0 ≠ x
        end script

        # For the last match only:
        if Array's predicate is false then return (Array's xN's length) + 1

        # For a match list (comment out line above):
        tell the Array
            if its predicate is false then ¬
                return the lastIndexOf(x, its xN) ¬
                    & (its xN's length) + 1
            return lastIndexOf(x, its xN)
        end tell
    end lastIndexOf
```

Then, all I need to do to obtain the result is:

```
    set L to {4, 24, 78, 32, 1.5, 32, 78, 14, 19, 78}
    get the lastIndexOf(maximum(L), L)
    --> 10
```

But, don't try and understand what I've done here just yet, and concentrate on understanding the `repeat` loop algorithms.

I've included these more advanced versions for completeness and for readers who may have wondered, had I left this out, why I didn't provide the most optimal solution I could have.

Whilst the algorithm used in these advanced versions remains the same (it doesn't look like it, but it is), the way the code is written makes these incredibly efficient for large itemed lists.

Note, however, I *haven't* included any **error handling**, so if you were to pass those handlers a list that contained non-numerical items, at least one of them would complain.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum value can be determined quite easy with help of AppleScriptObjC and Key-Value Coding

```
use AppleScript version "2.4" -- Yosemite (10.10) or later
use scripting additions

use framework "Foundation"

set numberList to {18, 18, 18, 18, 22, 21, 22}
set nsNumberList to current application's NSArray's arrayWithArray:numberList
set maxValue to nsNumberList's valueForKeyPath:"@max.intValue") as integer -- 22
```

If there is only one occurrence of that value of if you want only the index of the first occurrence write

```
set maxIndex to ((nsNumberList's indexOfObject:maxValue) as integer) + 1 -- AppleScript's lists are 1-based
```

If there are multiple occurrences of that value and you need all indexes use a loop (unfortunately the efficient native Cocoa API `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:` is not available in AppleScriptObjC)

```
set maxIndexes to {}
repeat with i from 0 to (count numberList) - 1 -- Cocoa's lists are 0-based
    if (maxValue's isEqualToNumber:(nsNumberList's objectAtIndex:i)) then
        set end of maxIndexes to i + 1
    end if
end repeat
maxIndexes -- {5, 7}
```